# Rename files by inserting a space before capital letters

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to understand how rename files using a batch.
I have some text like:

```
ArmiMagazineMarzo2021.pdf
ArteDossierN385Marzo2021.pdf
AstraMarzo2021.pdf
```

I want to rename it in this way:

```
Armi Magazine Marzo2021.pdf
Arte Dossier N385 Marzo2021.pdf
Astra Marzo2021.pdf
```

I have tried to insert a space before capital letters but I don't understand how. For example to replace all underscores `_` with the letter `M` to all files in current directory I can use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*_*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_=M!"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With substring replacement (`set var=%var:X=Y%`), `X` is treated case insensitive. You need another approach. I suggest [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

```
for %%a in (*) do ( 
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('echo %%a^|jrepl.bat "([A-Z])" " $1"') do (
    ECHO ren "%%a" "%%b"
  )
)
```

Output with your example files:

```
ren "ArmiMagazineMarzo2021" "Armi Magazine Marzo2021"
ren "ArteDossierN385Marzo2021" "Arte Dossier N385 Marzo2021"
ren "AstraMarzo2021" "Astra Marzo2021"
```

(don't forget to remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting and to provide the path to `jrepl.bat` if you don't have it in the same folder as your script)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to add also a space between letters and numbers, for example *ArmiMagazineMarzo2021* into **Armi Magazine Marzo 2021**? I try to replace `"([A-Z])" " $1"')` with `"([a-z])([0-9])" " $1"'`but doesn't work

Comment: @AlexDoc be mindful that what your asking in the above is a different task to the original question. If that is a requirement of the task you need to complete, please edit your question to include that information

Comment: use `"([A-Z]|\d{1,9})"` (a capital letter OR one to 9 digits). Also try `"([A-Z]|\d{4,9})"` (note the difference with `N385`)

Answer (score 0):

By splitting the filenames up, it's easier to do what you want.

For each file you call `ResolveFile`, this in it's turn determines the length of the filename by calling `StrLen` and loops over each character.

To verifying if a character is a capital, you replace the character in the list of it's lowercase alternatives (`lower`) with itself. As this is case insensitive `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` can become `Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` which is different. If the list `check` is the same as `lower`, it's not a capital.

To make this answer complete, you should add a Remove Diacritics option.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%a IN (*.*) DO (
  CALL :ResolveFile "%%a"
  REN "%%a" "!file!"
)

goto :eof

REM loop trough each character and replace where needed
:ResolveFile
SETLOCAL
  SET "s=%~1"
  SET lower=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  SET newfile=
  SET i=0
  CALL :StrLen %s%
  :ResolveFileInnerLoop
  IF %i% GEQ %length% GOTO ResolveFileEndLoop
  CALL SET char=%%s:~%i%,1%%
  IF %i% GTR 0 (
    CALL SET check=%%lower:%char%=%char%%%
    IF NOT "!check!"=="%lower%" (     
      SET char= !char!
    )
  )
  SET newfile=%newfile%%char%
  
  SET /A i=i+1
  GOTO ResolveFileInnerLoop
  :ResolveFileEndLoop
ENDLOCAL & SET file=%newfile%

GOTO :eof

REM StrLen function
:StrLen
SETLOCAL
  SET "s=#%~1"
  SET "len=0"
  FOR %%N IN (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) DO (
    IF "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      SET /a "len+=%%N"
      SET "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
ENDLOCAL & SET length=%len%

GOTO :eof
```